# Adding ListInstance to an application page

Tags: list-view-web-part

i have defined some site columns which were referenced by some content types. These are used for a ListDefinition and a ListInstance. (Everything is in one Visual Studio Project).
Now i would like to embed this list instance to an aplication page, beeing able to show that list and some other stuff at the same page. I definetly want to show the correct SharePoint list and not building (for example) a table.

In some other tests i was able to successfully use "WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart..."
but in that test i created the list by the SharePoint webpage and not through visual studio.
The problem with "WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart" is, that i need to enter the correct ListId.
I added the ID attribute in the Elements.xml of the ListInstance to avoid a dynamically built id but i always get the error message, that the list was not found (probably removed). 
I checked the list id of my list (in the address bar of my browser when i click edit list) and found out, that the list id changes every time i build/deploy my project although the id attribute of my list instance definition.

Can please somebody help me, correctly embedding my list?

Comment: Perhaps someone can explain me, why a list instance always get another id although i set the id attribute. If i could force it to keep the same id every time i build/deploy, my above problem would be solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the title of your list you could try something like this (here from Feature Event Receiver):

```
var web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
if (web == null) return;
var list = web.Lists["MyList"];
var manager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("MyPage.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared);
var xsltListViewWebPart = new XsltListViewWebPart { ListId = list.ID };
manager.AddWebPart(xsltListViewWebPart , "MyZone", manager.WebParts.Count + 1);
```

Comment: thank you for you answer. My problem is, that when i add this code in my Page_Load EventHandler the page (in your example "MyPage.aspx") will not be found on execution. Perhaps the page isn't built at this time?

Comment: I was thinking about running this in an [Feature Event Receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231604.aspx), so it will only be run once; when your Feature is activated (and the application page is deployed through some module).

Comment: Page_Load is part of when the page is accessed, as in opened normally in a browser. You can read about the [Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) on msdn.

Comment: When you say Application Page, do you really mean a Site Page deployed through a module, or a real Application Page, deployed to layouts?

Comment: if you mean application page read Andrey's response here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26508/is-it-possible-to-add-web-parts-to-an-application-page

Comment: Oh, that's right. event receiver wouldn't make much sense then. The code example is stil valid though, but...

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I ment an Application Page (selected from the templates menü when i click "add new..." menu). I think it's that one, deployed to layouts. For me it looks like a default asp.net page.

Answer (score 0):

When your list is created, the instance of this list is saved to the content data base, in this time the data base assign a new ID for your list to be sure that this ID is unique.

I think that you can use [ListUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.listurl.aspx) property of XsltListViewWebPart instead of list ID in web part definition. It is unique value for each web.