# Add webpart to application page programatically

Tags: application-pages, custom-web-parts

I want to add a webpart on page load to the application page, I want to deal with the webpart like any other control, like adding a label in the page load function, but I want to view this webpart each time I load this application page.

Comment: Pls have a look at this discussion where they are adding webpart to Edit page. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9442/how-to-programmatically-add-a-webpart-to-a-page

Comment: Check out Delegate controls in Sharepoint

Answer (score 1):

If your application page does not contains webpart zones then you must put on the page as webcontrols:

1.Register your namespace that your webpart resides in

2.Then add your webcontrol

[Link to source](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/26509/20912)