# Include webpart into farm solution page

Tags: web-part

I am using an application page in my solution.

I would like to include a webpart but i don't know how...

I tried to use the object tag, it works but i cannot get the element in 100% height and i don't want to use in pixels because i want to display the page without scrolling.

Can you tell me how to fix this issue? Am I using the best method?

Waiting for you help..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can not include web parts inside application pages. It is not a common practice. From MSDN:

> Application pages are not subject to the same restrictions as site
>   pages. They allow in-line code without restriction. They cannot,
>   however, use dynamic Web Parts or Web Part zones or be modified using
>   SharePoint Designer.

Source: [SharePoint Page Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa979592%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

In this question you can see some alternative paths. Although revise fine if you must use one or find another way to solve the same problem.

[Is it possible to add web parts to an application page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26508/is-it-possible-to-add-web-parts-to-an-application-page/26509)