# Lot's of visual webparts

Tags: 2010, visual-web-part, productivity

My question is pretty straightforward: Is it OK to have a lot of webparts on a Sharepoint platform?

The thing is that we would like to make the development of our projects (different kind of projects on different sites) based on visual webpart templates. One service could be up to 10 webparts. We might have more than 100 webparts overall.

Does anyone had such experience? Will this affect on productivity? Would you suggest some other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum number of web parts per page is 50 by default. This can be extended by increasing the number of `<WebPartLimits MaxZoneParts="50" PropertySize="1048576" />` in **web.config**-file.

For what comes to your question: It is OK.

The performance will definitely depend on your server's setup and the visualized content. The amount of data to be visualized and the time it takes to run each visualization obviously increase the page load time. Dividing the visual web parts to different pages according to their use cases/categories/x is therefore what I'd suggest. It becomes very complicated to predict the performance even if we know the "numbers" beforehand, as there are still other variables even harder to consider (other sites ran on the server, connection quality).

Comment: According to our design scheme we gonna add several webparts or even one per page. In this case I believe it is ok. But how about the big number of a webparts in a webpart gallery (like for instance 1000 visual webparts) while they are distributed among projects? I agree that this also depends on a hardware, but generally speaking are there any other solutions or design patterns? Should we look for an application pages for instance or smth else?

Comment: @user2992532 for what I know web parts are treated as *documents* in the web parts gallery, which then again acts as a *library*. Thus the item limitation is a fair 30,000,000 in SP2010. The use of application pages isn't recommended (have a look: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26508/is-it-possible-to-add-web-parts-to-an-application-page)