# Ribbon missing on SharePoint 2013 application page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, application-pages

I have deployed an application page (.aspx) located in some folder in 15 hives.
Now I am not able to add OOTB web parts or format text as SharePoint ribbon is missing. I guess it is because of default.master

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ChangePassword.aspx.cs" Inherits="SP.FBA.Forms.ChangePassword" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a normal behavior (`it's not related to assigned master page`), The application page does not have a ribbon because it is not customized,

[image]

In case you need to add your web part, you should add it as a user control, by the way, it's not recommended to do that in the application page,

For more details check [Is it possible to add web parts to an application page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26508/is-it-possible-to-add-web-parts-to-an-application-page)